# seat reservation not working

Tags: php, mysql

I've been doing a lot of research but I guess I still didn't find the answers. This is a seat reservation and I'm not so good in php and mysql. So here's my code:

reservation.php code:

```
<?php 
mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die (mysql_error());
mysql_select_db('seat_reservation') or die (mysql_error());

$insert = mysql_query("INSERT INTO reservation (chair_status, room_id, chair_number) VALUES (0, 400, 05)");
                                ?>
</td>
 <div id="popupContact">
  <a id="popupContactClose">x</a>
 <center><form method = "POST" action="reserve.php">
<?php
$query = mysql_query("SELECT chair_status FROM reservation WHERE room_id = '400' AND chair_number = '05'");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
$_SESSION['roomno'] = $row['room_id'];
$_SESSION['chairnum'] = $row['chair_number'];
}

?>
```

reserve.php code:

```
<?php
$name = $_POST['student_name'];
$stud_id = $_POST['stud_id'];
$room_id = $_SESSION['roomno'];
$chair_num = $_SESSION['chairnum'];

mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die (mysql_error());
mysql_select_db('seat_reservation') or die (mysql_error());

$query = mysql_query("SELECT chair_status FROM reservation WHERE room_id = '$room_id' AND chair_number = '$chair_num'");
if($query == 0)
{
$insert = mysql_query("UPDATE reservation SET chair_status = 1, student_name = '$name', stud_id = '$stud_id' WHERE room_id = '$room_id' AND chair_number = '$chair_num'");
}
else


die ("Sorry, seat taken! <br />Redirecting...<meta http-equiv='refresh' content=2;reservation.php>");

?>
```

my problem is that, when I reserve a seat, it tells me that the seat is taken even if the chair_status field is 0. When I checked the DB, it successfully inserted with chair_status of 0. I don't know which part is wrong. I really need your help, thank you!

Comment: for starters, you don't escape your SQL queries. and second of all, you still use mysql_

Comment: @ColeJohnson That comment is supremely unhelpful unless you provide the asker context on what you're talking about.  Not everyone is aware of PDO or MySQLi, and the planned, [though not yet documented in the manual](http://us.php.net/manual/en/ref.mysql.php) deprecations of the `mysql_*()` functions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. In `reservation.php`, you `SELECT` only `chair_status` but then try to access `$row['room_id']` and `$row['chair_number']`: neither are in the resultset.  However, both are already known since they were fixed in the `WHERE` clause of the query, therefore one could use those values without resorting to the MySQL query.
2. Even if you wanted to use such a query to set the `$_SESSION` variables, it is daft to loop over the resultset overridding those variables with each result.  Better to `LIMIT` the query and use only one resulting record.
3. However, you probably wanted to *output* form elements rather than set `$_SESSION` variables in order that the user can then choose which of the available seats they wish to reserve?  In which case, you probably meant to include `chair_status = 0` in your filter criteria.
4. The return value of the `mysql_query` function is a resource identifier; comparing this against 0 in `reserve.php` is probably not what you had intended.  Perhaps you wanted [`mysql_num_rows`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-num-rows.php) instead?
5. Please stop writing new code with the ancient MySQL extension: it is no longer maintained and the community has begun the [deprecation process](http://news.php.net/php.internals/53799). Instead you should use either the improved [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) extension or the [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) abstraction layer.
6. Please avoid putting variables (and especially those which come from your user) into your SQL, which makes you vulnerable to SQL injection.  You should instead use prepared statements, with which your variables can be passed to MySQL as parameters that do not get evaluated for SQL.  Read about [Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

You probably mean `if (mysql_num_rows($query) == 0) {`. The way it is your are checking if there is an error with the query, not the number of rows returned. [Check the docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-num-rows.php) for more information.

Also, this might be optional, but use braces to enclose your `else` statement. And it might be better to use [mysqli](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) instead of `mysql_...` functions as mentioned in your comments. Or just escape the user input before adding it to the query string.

Answer (score 0):

use mysql_num_rows for checking if records exist..

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT chair_status FROM reservation WHERE room_id = '$room_id' AND chair_number = '$chair_num'");
$rows = mysql_num_rows($query);
if($rows == 0)
{
$insert = mysql_query("UPDATE reservation SET chair_status = 1, student_name = '$name', stud_id = '$stud_id' WHERE room_id = '$room_id' AND chair_number = '$chair_num'");
}
```